# Adding tooltip to the facebook share icon

Tags: facebook, tooltip, share, facebook-like

I want to add (layout: box-count, action type: like) a facebook like and a share button with tooltips to my website. I am using for code generating the following site: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/

The "Like" has a tooltip, but the "Share" button not. I am using the "fb:like" tag for embedding the facebook buttons.

How can I add a tooltip to the "Share" button too? I am neither using PHP nor CSS (don't want to use it). Please consider it when answering.

Thank you for all of your useful tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Like" text you see when hovering over the like button is caused by the `title` value in a div.

It looks like this for the Like button:

[image]

So for a similar share button it would result in something like this:

```
<div class="blah" title="Share"></div>
```

Comment: It only works, when I move the mouse inside the FB-area, but outside of the buttons' area (so if I move the mouse on the "empty space" of the facebook buttons' area).

Comment: @A.V. Do you mind posting a photo, this sounds tricky to describe

Answer (score 0):

Facebook uses iframes, assign the tip to the Facebook generated iframe. You will find it by analysing the source code

Comment: I am using another method. Not the iframe-variant, but the "fb:like"-variant.